# Integrate OpenAPI 3.0 schema for spring boot json response test

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jsonschema, openapi

I write OPENAPI 3.0 yaml file as the documentation for java REST api project. It can be nicely rendered with [ReDoc](https://redoc.ly/). And in order to help other developers and our customers to use the API I should always keep the java response java the same with the `OPENAPI yaml` schema definition.

So...it there some tools to help use the OPENAPI yaml schema validate JAVA Response?

I have seen some tools like [`rest-assured`](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-assured-json-schema) can use `json-schema` for response validation. But it seems that the [OPENAPI schema](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/keywords/) is a little bit different from the json validation. I can not use it directly.

Comment: JSON Schema and OpenAPI JSON Schema are similar but not the same. You must use OpenAPI specific tooling. OpenAPI 3.1 will likely see support for pure JSON Schema, but tooling has to catch up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using https://github.com/mikunn/openapi2schema. This package help translate openapi definitions into valid json schema draft 4 version. And I can then use rest-assured to validate the json response with this json schema file.